# Create a window with 2 separated view-parts using bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to create a command using bash which creates a window with 2 view-parts on it.

The first 9/10 of the window's height is a scrollable text-viewer (read-only). The last 1/10 of the window is a menu which listens to hot-keys like

^S - save

^C - clear

Is it possible to implement this using bash? If yes, can you please provide a minimal example of that.

Thanks.

---

Update.

I'm going to make a cli tool. So users should be able to install and run it from terminal.
Not necessary to use bash, it is just for personal use. What tools should I use?

Comment: I can't tell you how to do it. bash feels like the wrong tool for it. Start with the `tput` man page.

Comment: For personal use, I'd use `tmux` for it.

Comment: `dialog` might be your friend for this, but for `^C` -- that is something you would need to `trap` for.  Coding an application like this directly in shell may not be trivial at all.  I think we need more details as to your purpose to determine feasibility.

Comment: @glennjackman thx for reply. updated

Comment: @MichaelBack thx for reply. updated

Comment: You can also look at zenity and yad: they are command-line tools to create GUI interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found what I want.

The most similar what I found is `nano` text editor, which is based on `curses` library.